# Adding @Cachable to entities has no effect

Tags: java, jpa, caching, second-level-cache

I want to cache some JPA entities to improve performance. So I set-up caching for my spring-boot application and added the [javax.persistence.Cachable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html) annotation to an entity.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

This does nothing. If I watch the application startup log and saving and retreiving entities, I can see that no cache is configured for the entity and nothing is written or read from the cache.

However if I change `@Cacheable` to `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` the caching starts to work as expected.

Since I'd like to stick to standard JPA annotations, the question is what's missing to get `@Cacheable` working?

This are my configuration files:

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=jcache
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.provider=org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider

logging.level.org.hibernate.cache=DEBUG
logging.level.org.ehcache=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener=TRACE
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-transactions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the JPA 2.0 specification, if you want to selectively cache entities using the `@Cacheable` annotation, you're supposed to specify a "share cache mode".

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ALL
```

Comment: This helps indeed. However I went for ENABLE_SELECTIVE instead of ALL. ALL means cache everything regardless of any annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cache mode and annotations, there are some properties/hints which control caching of entities.

There is a Cache section in the JPA developer guide:
https://cmobilecom.com/docs/jpa/latest/devguide/index.html